# jquery if click remove from old id display:block

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have following code. If the a tag is clicked it should remove the display:block and set it again of display:none.
This is the html part. There are 20 section (divs like this)

```
   <!-- Reservieren Sektion 15 --> 
    <div class="section black" id="section16">
         <ul class="nav">
                <ul id="flyout">

                    <li><a class="fly" href="#url"><b>Wir</b><!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
                    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->

                    <li><a href="#section15"><b>Reservieren</b></a></li>

                    <li><a href="#section16"><b><font color="#FFFFFF">Feiern</font></b></a></li>

                    <li><a href="#section17"><b>Arbeiten</b></a></li>

                    <li><a href="#section18"><b>Kaufen</b></a></li>

                    <li><a class="fly" href="#url"><b>Vernetzen</b><!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
                    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#section19"><b>Freunde</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section20"><b>Facebook & Qype</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section21"><b>Presse</b></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#section22"><b>Impressum</b></a></li>

                </ul>

         </ul>
```

And this the jquery

$(this) is the next sections id, but i want do set display none for the last id which is clicked.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a").click(function () {
        var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
            if($(addressValue).css("display") == "block"){

                $(addressValue+i).css("display","none");    
            }

        $(addressValue).css("display","block");
        });
    </script>;
```

Can someone help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var lastel;
$("a").click(function () {
    if(lastel){
        lastel.hide();
    }

    lastel = $($(this).attr("href"));
    addressValue.toggle()
});
```

Comment: this doesnt work. $(this) is the next sections id, but i want do set display none for the last id which is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    $("a").click(function() {
        $($(this).attr("href")).toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done all well u have just missed `else` of your `if` condition

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("a").click(function () {
        var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
            if($(addressValue).css("display") == "block"){

                $(addressValue+i).css("display","none");    
            }
            else{                                   //You missed this else
               $(addressValue).css("display","block");
            }
        });
    </script>;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error ('+i') in your javascript code:

```
$(addressValue+i).css("display","none");
```

Should be:

```
$(addressValue).css("display","none");
```

By the way, your code is working as expected. When clicking on 'Feiern' link, the #section16 div display is passed to 'none' and then back to 'block'.

If your need is to hide all sections divs but the one clicked, you can do as following:

```
$('a').click(function () {
   var addressValue = $(this).attr('href');
   $('.section').css('display', 'none');
   $(addressValue).css('display','block');
});
```

assuming that there is no conflict using the '.section' selector.

Comment: first its on display:none when clicking on the link is set to display block and when i click on a other link then last one(which is set on display block) should change to display none and the actual one should change on display block